# How do I use javascript to click a button with no on click event?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I use javascript to click a button with no id?  Normally, I would do something like:

```
document.getElementById("button").click();
```

here is the html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://example.com/account/login" id="customer_login" method="post"><input name="form_type" type="hidden" value="customer_login" />
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓" />
  <label for="customer_email" class="label">Email Address</label>
  <input type="email" value="" name="customer[email]" id="customer_email" class="text" />

  <label for="customer_password" class="label">Password</label>
  <input type="password" value="" name="customer[password]" id="customer_password" class="text" size="16" />

 <div class="action_bottom">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    <span class="note">or <a href="http://example.com">Return to Store</a></span>
  </div>
  </form>
```

I can fill in the email and password boxes like this:

```
document.getElementById("customer_email").value = "myemail@mail.com";
document.getElementById("customer_password").value = "passwordtoenter";
```

Comment: The `.click()` function will trigger any click handlers bound to the targeted element. It does not have the same effect as when a user mouse clicks an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate element by class using [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) method. This method returns array-like list, so you need to know exactly which button you're trying to click. Assuming that there's only one button with class "btn" or if this button comes first in the document flow - you can do something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use jQuery to accomplish this.  Using pure javascript seems more hipster these days than practical.  For example:

```
$('#customer_email').val("myemail@mail.com");
$('#customer_password").val("passwordtoenter");
$('#customer_login .btn').click();
```

The selectors in jQuery make life a whole lot easier in JS.  I'm not sure what the intent is for having javascript call the click rather than letting the form submit itself.  If you are going to do some custom submit logic you could use:

```
$("#customer_login .btn').on('click', function(e) {
  //if you need to prevent the click events default action
  e.preventDefault();
  //Custom logic here
});
```

Comment: Excuse me, but there are valid, non-hipster reasons for using plain JS on a page, such as keeping the page extremely light.  I use jQuery heavily in my web application, but I have some cases where the weight is just not worth it.  I would eliminate the editorial sentence "Using pure javascript ... practical"

Comment: There clearly are cases when you would use pure JS.  But these days that is an edge case.  jQuery is small, and can easily be gotten over a CDN if you don't want to host it yourself.  Even on 3g mobile connections jQuery is not a big burden and as long as it is cached is basically a one time hit.  My point being, jQuery should be leveraged in javascript rich apps.  If you do almost no JS, just go pure JS.  Otherwise it is a hipster choice to ignore libraries like jQuery pure and simple.